# How to exit from the loop when reach to the last row in datagridview using DataGridRowPostPaint event

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview

I have items in a datagridview using windows application C#, and I created the event `DataGrid_RowPostPaint` to generate serial number for each row in the datagridview.

Now when I save the data it is saving but not exits from the window and hang, I used break point to follow up why its hang after save, then I found that its looping in this event and not exit when reach to the last row in datagridview.

This is the code:

```
private void TestsDataGrid_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    this.TestsDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Serial"].Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
}
```

How to update the code in the event to exit from the event and end the loop when reach to the last row in datagridview.

Comment: Huh? I see no loop in your code. __The rowXXX events are always called for each Row separately__. You can abort each when needed.

Comment: @TaW in breakpoint its not exit from the event how to exit from event when  last row reached?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking?! Did you understand my comment?? When the last row has been processed it will not be called again. __Unless, of course a new reason to do some painting__ comes along..You are setting a Cell value there, which may be the issue. The event is meant to influence the way the row is painted, not the values it contains!!

Comment: @TaW How to abort and exit from the event , what to change in my code to exit from the method when reach the last row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app hangs because changing the value in the paint event will cause an **endless loop**.

The event `RowPostPaint` is called after the row has been painted. If you change a cell value it will have to be called **again** to show the new value!

Move that code to some other event, maybe `CellValueChanged`! Here is an example that sets the 2nd cell value to the current second after the cell in the 1st column has been changed for the 1st time:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int col1 = 0;
    int col2 = 1;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == col1  && dataGridView1[col1  , e.RowIndex] == null)
        dataGridView1[col2 , e.RowIndex].Value = DateTime.Now.Second + "s";
}
```

Do adapt to your conditions etc..!

To sum it up: You are using the wrong event to change cell values! - 
**Do not change any cell values in a Paint event!!**

Comment: Yes, this.  Never change values in a Paint event. Paint brushes are for painting, not for hammering nails. Use events for their correct purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The paint event is often called by the top event handler of the windows application system manager.

It is done each time that the control refresh its content.

It is done for example when moving or resizing the form, moving the mouse over the control, passing from top to bottom z-order...

It is why it seems to be a loop.

You can define a condition for when you don't want to paint using a flag like that at the beginning of the method:

```
private void TestsDataGrid_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
  if ( !paintRequired ) return;
  this.TestsDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Serial"].Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
}
```

On the form load put:

```
paintRequired = true;
```

Somewhere in your code after loading the data from database, write:

```
paintRequired = true;
TestsDataGrid.Refresh();
paintRequired = false;
```

Do that every time the data is changed.

But you should use a calculated column:

[Creating Expression Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns)

Comment: Can you post complete method solution , I tried it but not working.